# Alternative systray

Tags: unity, gnome, indicator, system-tray

13.04 has dropped support for old-style systray indicators. This may or may not be a step in the right direction in the long term, but it's extremely inconvenient in the short term.

There are at least four apps that I regularly use that have a systray icon, and half of those are completely unusable without it. I going to need a work-around to get by.

In the old days it used to be possible to run a gnome-panel in a Unity desktop, and get the old gnome2 widgets and indicators that way. However, whilst gnome-panel still runs, it also seems to have moved on and there's no way to configure a systray any more (or is there?)

Does anybody know of any alternative systray providers that might be compatible with a Unity desktop? Maybe xfce or lxde has one?

---

Edit:

I'm aware of the PPA with a modified Unity, but that's not ideal, and anyway I'm running Saucy, so that doesn't apply.

Comment: I know that Cairo Dock has an 'old style' systray plug in, but I don't think that this is what you are looking for.

Comment: @SimplySimon: You mean [this](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/cairo-dock/)? That looks cool, but ideally I'm looking for something more discreet. Do you think it will configure "down" a little?

Comment: And there is proposed version of Unity that soon will come into updates repository. Do not mention you use Saucy else someone will flag your question ;)

Comment: Yes that's the one. It should do, just create a new dock on the top with it **Always on top** with tiny icons and add the **Notification Area Old** applet to it then make the main bar always hidden. It should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the options I've tried. I've set this to "community wiki", so please add other answers if you have any.

[**xfce4-panel**](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/xfce4-panel)

[image: xfce4-panel with only a systray added]

- Pros

  - Easy to set up
  - No extra nonsense (unless you want it)
  - Works with Unity Desktop
  - Size configurable
- Cons

  - If positioned near the edge of the screen maximised windows will not use the whole screen.
  - Can't be positioned on top of the Unity panel because it gets lost behind.

[**Cairo Dock**](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/cairo-dock)

[image: Cairo Dock systray]

- Pros

  - The systray is nice and small, and the background is transparent
  - Works with Unity Desktop
  - Does not affect size/position of maximized windows.
- Cons

  - Systray cannot be placed on top of the Unity panel
  - There's a whole extra Mac-style launcher that can't be disabled

    - It does auto-hide though.
  - Although Cairo supports both old and new-style notifications, they don't co-exist.
  - Can only be moved around with <kbd>Alt</kbd>-drag

In all cases, the systrays do not coexist well, and I've found I sometimes had to restart the apps to get the icons to reappear. After some fiddling about I seem to have got them very confused.